# NullPointerException in onResume

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have two **activities MainActivity  and SecondActivity**

Code in **activity MainActivity .java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMarkerClickListener {

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
      databaseobj = new AppDatabase(MainActivity.this, null);
      listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.store_listview);
      noSavedMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_msg);
      ..
      ..
      ..//Other code logic
      ..
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
      if (databaseobj.GetAll() != -1) { //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
      listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
      noSavedMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
      }
      super.onResume();
  }
}
```

I am getting the null pointer exception after returning from another activity;

**MainActivity -> new intent to SecondActivity**

**SecondActivity->finish() then MainActivity-> onResume() NULL POINTER EXCEPTION**

Please help!

Comment: what is `NoSavedMsg`?

Comment: 1. How are the variables declared? 2. Usually `super.onResume()` is first and not last in the overridden method.

Comment: did any of the given solution solved your problem? If did then you should accept the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextView` name is `noSavedMsg` but you are trying set visibility to a view named `NoSavedMsg`...where these two are not same.

Change this line...

```
NoSavedMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to...

```
noSavedMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: sorry its noSavedMsg only; but why is it giving null pointer exception on the earlier lines (i.e. On databaseobj and On  listview)

Comment: If your code crashes on `listview` then it can't possible further after that line...so, `listview` and `databaseobj` isn't null...the `noSavedMsg` is null and application is crashing in this line.

Answer (score 0):

You sure you need that capital `N` there?

```
NoSavedMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And not:

```
noSavedMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: sorry its noSavedMsg only; but why is it giving null pointer exception on the earlier lines (i.e. On databaseobj and On  listview)

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseobj = new AppDatabase(MainActivity.this, null);
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.store_listview);
noSavedMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_msg);
```

Add this code to the onResume method and see if it works.

Comment: Probably because when you change activity, the first activity frees its resources, which implies destroying any variables. What you could maybe try is using startActivityForResult instead of startactivity (if you haven't already)